# Why does my loop iterate only twice?

Tags: c

I have defined two structs and when I loop to set their values, it only loop twice as printf return. Any ideas?

```
typedef struct {
  int x;
  int y;
  unsigned char status;
} Cell;

typedef struct {
  int sizeX;
  int sizeY;
  Cell cell[];
} World;

int main() {
  int i, x, y;
  i = 0;
  World grid;
  grid.sizeX = 10;
  grid.sizeY = 10;

  for (x = 0; x < grid.sizeX; x++) {
    for (y = 0; y < grid.sizeY; y++) {
      Cell cell;
      cell.x = x;
      cell.y = y;

      printf("%d,%d: ", cell.x, cell.y);

      grid.cell[i] = cell;
      i++;
    }
  }

    return 0;
}
```

---

EDIT :

Correct answer given below, thanks for comments and your patience for a C noob !

Comment: `Cell cell[];` !!

Comment: An array of Cells defined by the struct, is that wrong ?

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the code with a debugger? And you should definitely read more about [*flexible array members*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flexible_array_member) because what you're doing now is writing out of bounds of a zero-sized array, leading to *undefined behavior*.

Comment: You need to reserve space before using it. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c/1119/structs/10850/flexible-array-members#t=201706041649526651324)

Comment: Ok, looking at this, thanks.

Comment: Compile with all warnings & debug info (`gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`). **Use the debugger `gdb`** and [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/). Read more about [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)

Comment: "Loop only twice" - trashes neighbouring variables.

Comment: You need to define the size of the array. Either directly inside the structure (`Cell cell[100];`) or using the [flexible array member](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.2.1), or with `malloc()`.

Comment: Would you move your answer (merged into the end of your question) to an answer box proper please? Click on 'Answer Your Question' to do this. Self-answers are welcomed here.

Comment: I've achieved this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `World` struct has a flexible array member as the last element.  There is actually no space set aside for that member.  As a result, you write off the end of the struct when you write to the array, resulting in undefined behavior.

You need to declare a `World *`  and use `malloc` to allocate space for the struct plus the array.

```
World *world = malloc(sizeof(World) + 10 * 10 * sizeof(Cell));
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I got difficulties now to set my world.sizeX or use it in my loop. All of this just means I didn't understood all of this. But kicking myself to read more about flexible array.

Answer (score 2):

`grid.cell[]` is not have been allocated any memory space. You should allocate it a memory by adding following line before starting of the loop:

```
 grid.cell = Cell[100];
```

The size `100` is based on the fact that `grid.sizeX = 10;` and `grid.sizeY = 10;`. There is no need of using `malloc()` because the size is fixed.

If size is not fixed for `grid.sizeX` and `grid.sizeY`then, you should add following line instead of `grid.cell = Cell[100];`:

```
 grid.cell = (Cell*)malloc(sizeof(Cell) *(grid.xSize  * grid.ySize ));
```

The line `World *grid = malloc(sizeof(World) + xSize * ySize * sizeof(Cell));` which is added by you is just a tricked way and not much clear. Even it is logically correct!!!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the results :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define LIVE 1
#define DEAD 0
#define xSize 10
#define ySize 10

typedef struct {
  int x;
  int y;
  unsigned char status;
} Cell;

typedef struct {
  int sizeX;
  int sizeY;
  Cell cell[1];
} World;

int main() {
  int i, x, y;
  i = 0;
  World *grid = malloc(sizeof(World) + xSize * ySize * sizeof(Cell));;
  grid->sizeX = xSize;
  grid->sizeY = ySize;

  for (x = 0; x < grid->sizeX; x++) {
    for (y = 0; y < grid->sizeY; y++) {
      Cell cell;
      cell.x = x;
      cell.y = y;
      cell.status = DEAD;

      printf("%d,%d: ", cell.x, cell.y);

      grid->cell[i] = cell;
      i++;
    }
  }

    return 0;
}
```